How to move the hamburger menu icon from right to left in DragTarget element
is there a way to move the hambuger menu from the right side to the left side of the DragTarget element?
the goal is for the hamburger menu to be first followed by the x icon.
i tried chatgpt all morning but it seems to be doing terrible today.
i could not find other stackoverflows with something similar.

import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

var uuid = Uuid();

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sys_ui_form_section = [
    {"sys_id": "l1", "column_number": 2, 'sys_title': "First section title"},
    {"sys_id": "l2", "column_number": 2, 'sys_title': "Second section title"},
  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {"sys_id": "ste1", "sys_ui_form_section_id": "l1", "sys_ui_form_element_id": "fe1"},

  ];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sys_ui_form_element = [
    {"sys_id": "fe1", "column_id": "c1", "sys_order": 1, "sys_type": null},

  ];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> columns = [
    {'sys_id': 'c1', 'sys_label': 'Label 1', 'sys_name': 'Name 1'},

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Drag and Drop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DragDropExample(
        columns: columns,
        sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element: sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element,
        sys_ui_form_element: sys_ui_form_element,
        sys_ui_form_section: sys_ui_form_section,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DragDropExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> sys_ui_form_section;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> sys_ui_form_element;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> columns;

  DragDropExample({
    required this.columns,
    required this.sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element,
    required this.sys_ui_form_element,
    required this.sys_ui_form_section,
  });

  @override
  _DragDropExampleState createState() => _DragDropExampleState();
}

class _DragDropExampleState extends State<DragDropExample> {
  late bool _is_loading = true;

  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sys_ui_form_section = [];
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element = [];
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _sys_ui_form_element = [];
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> _columns = [];

  late List<Map<String, dynamic>?> _grid_data = [];
  bool _hovering_over_last_row = false;

  int _hoveredIndex = -1;
  late String _hoveredSectionId = '';

  Map<String, TextEditingController> _controllers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _sys_ui_form_section = widget.sys_ui_form_section;
    _sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element = widget.sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element;
    _sys_ui_form_element = widget.sys_ui_form_element;
    _columns = widget.columns;

    for (var section in _sys_ui_form_section) {
      _controllers[section['sys_id']] = TextEditingController(text: section['sys_title']);
    }
    _populate_grid_data();
    _is_loading = false;
  }

  void _populate_grid_data() {
    print("_populate_grid_data()\n");
    for (var ste in _sys_ui_form_section_to_sys_ui_form_element) {
      var form_element = _sys_ui_form_element.firstWhere((fe) => fe['sys_id'] == ste['sys_ui_form_element_id']);
      var column = _columns.firstWhere((col) => col['sys_id'] == form_element['column_id']);

      _columns.removeWhere((element) => element['sys_id'] == form_element['column_id']);

      _grid_data.add({
        'sys_id': form_element['sys_id'],
        'sys_label': column['sys_label'],
        'sys_name': column['sys_name'],
        'column_id': column['sys_id'],
        'section_id': ste['sys_ui_form_section_id'],
        'isDraggable': true,
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var controller in _controllers.values) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Drag and Drop Example'),
      ),
      body: _is_loading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // column menu
                SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _columns.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Draggable<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                        data: _columns[index],
                        feedback: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              _columns[index]['sys_label'],
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        childWhenDragging: Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            _columns[index]['sys_label'],
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                          child: Text(
                            _columns[index]['sys_label'],
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                // column grid
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: _sys_ui_form_section.map((section) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              section['sys_title'],
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: DragTarget<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                              builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                                var items = _grid_data.where((data) => data!['section_id'] == section['sys_id']).toList();
                                if (_hoveredIndex != -1 && _hoveredIndex <= items.length && _hoveredSectionId == section['sys_id']) {
                                  items.insert(_hoveredIndex, {
                                    'sys_id': 'temp',
                                    'sys_label': 'Drop here',
                                    'sys_name': 'Drop here',
                                    'column_id': 'temp',
                                    'section_id': section['sys_id'],
                                    'isDraggable': false,
                                  });
                                }
                                return ReorderableListView(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                                        newIndex -= 1;
                                      }
                                      final item = items.removeAt(oldIndex);
                                      items.insert(newIndex, item);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  children: items.map((data) {
                                    return ListTile(
                                      key: Key(data!['sys_id']),
                                      title: DragTarget<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                                        builder: (context, candidateData, rejectedData) {
                                          return Draggable<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                                            data: data,
                                            feedback: Material(
                                              color: Colors.transparent,
                                              child: Container(
                                                color: Colors.blue,
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  data['sys_label'],
                                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            child: Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                              ),
                                              child: Row(children: [
                                                if (data['sys_id'] != 'temp')
                                                  IconButton(
                                                    icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      _add_column_back(data);
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                Text(data['sys_label']),
                                              ]),
                                            ),
                                            onDragCompleted: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _grid_data.remove(data);
                                              });
                                            },
                                          );
                                        },
                                        onWillAccept: (dragData) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _hoveredIndex = items.indexOf(data);
                                            _hoveredSectionId = section['sys_id'];
                                          });
                                          return true;
                                        },
                                        onLeave: (data) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _hoveredSectionId = '';
                                            _hoveredIndex = -1;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        onAccept: (dragData) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _hoveredSectionId = '';

                                            _hoveredIndex = -1;
                                            _grid_data.remove(data);
                                            _grid_data.add({
                                              ...dragData!,
                                              'section_id': section['sys_id'],
                                            });
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                );
                              },
                              onWillAccept: (data) => true,
                              onAccept: (data) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _hoveredIndex = -1;
                                  _grid_data.removeWhere((element) => element!['sys_id'] == data!['sys_id']);
                                  _grid_data.add({
                                    ...data!,
                                    'section_id': section['sys_id'],
                                  });
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }


}


all the code is included so you can litrally run it in your machine.
